# Use awk to extract column data with multiple names (UNIX)

Tags: unix, awk, subset, multiple-columns, large-data

Hey I am newer to using Linux and I have a large dataset with 5k columns all with different names comparing patient data. I want to subset the "PC" data from the other groups (such as BC, PR... etc). There are about 100 members for the PC all labeled PC****. where **** is a case number.

Data looks like this (Although delimiter = \t ):

| ID_REF | BC0010 | BC0011 | PC0023 | PC0013 | PR0007 | PR0053 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Gene1 | 1.177703095 | -1.32116828 | -2.176250582 | -2.079342976 | -1.427146954 | 10.64102737 |
| Gene2 | 1.177703095 | -1.32116828 | -2.176250582 | -2.079342976 | -1.427146954 | 10.64102737 |
| Gene3 | 1.177703095 | -1.32116828 | -2.176250582 | -2.079342976 | -1.427146954 | 10.64102737 |

What I am trying to get is (again with delimiter = \t):

| ID_REF | PC0023 | PC0013 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Gene1 | -2.176250582 | -2.079342976 |
| Gene2 | -2.176250582 | -2.079342976 |
| Gene3 | -2.176250582 | -2.079342976 |

So far I have tried :

```
 $ awk -F/t -v col=*PC 'NR==1{for(i=1;i<=NF;i++){if($i==col){c=i;break}} print $c} NR>1{print $c}' data.txt > pcData.txt
```

However for some reason this doesn't subset the data and I end up getting all columns returned.

I am not sure what to put into col=??? to make this work.

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1st issue is the input field delimiter (`-F/t`); wrong symbol for a tab; a couple options: `-F$'\t'` or in a `BEGIN{}` block (eg, `BEGIN { FS="\t" }`); since it looks like you want to maintain a tab as the output field delimiter then one idea:

```
# replace

awk -F/t 'NR==1 ....

# with

awk 'BEGIN { FS=OFS="\t" } NR==1 ....
```

2nd issue is the check for a column name starting with `PC`; you'll have problems getting awk to understand what `*PC` is supposed to mean; since you want to know about column names that *start* with `PC`, one idea:

```
awk -v col='PC' 'NR==1{for (i=1;i<=NF;i++) if ( index($i,col)==1 ) ....'
```

3rd issue is that you want to build a list (how about an array?) to store a list of columns of interest; you're currently breaking out of your `NR==1` loop on the first match where what you want to do is keep track of the column numbers (`i`) for all matches; since you also want to keep the 1st column, something like:

```
if ( index($i,col)==1 || i==1 ) cols[++c]=i
```

... then for all input lines you print the columns represented by the numbers in the array.

Rolling all of this into a complete script (and changing some names):

```
awk -v pfx='PC' '
BEGIN { FS=OFS="\t" }
NR==1 { for (i=1;i<=NF;i++)
            if ( (index($i,pfx)==1) || i==1)
               cols[++c]=i
      }
      { for (i=1;i<=c;i++)
            printf "%s%s", (i==1 ? "" : OFS), $(cols[i])
        print ""
      }
' data.txt
```

This generates:

```
ID_REF  PC0023  PC0013
Gene1   -2.176250582    -2.079342976
Gene2   -2.176250582    -2.079342976
Gene3   -2.176250582    -2.079342976
```

Comment: This worked perfectly and thank you for all your explanations helped me learn alot.

Comment: If you change `printf "%s%s", (i==1 ? "" : OFS), $(cols[i])` to `printf "%s%s", $(cols[i]), (i<c ? OFS : ORS)` then you won't need the `print ""`

Answer (score 0):

In [TXR Lisp](https://nongnu.org/txr):

```
$ txr getpc.tl < data
ID_REF  PC0023  PC0013
Gene1   -2.176250582    -2.079342976
Gene2   -2.176250582    -2.079342976
Gene3   -2.176250582    -2.079342976
```

Code:

```
(let* ((header (spl "\t" (get-line)))
       (wanted-cols (where (f^$ #/ID_REF|PC.*/) header)))
  (put-line (join-with "\t" (select header wanted-cols)))
  (whilet ((line (get-line))
           (row (if line (spl "\t" line))))
    (put-line (join-with "\t" (select row wanted-cols)))))
```

The `where` function returns the indices (zero based positions) of a sequence where some predicate is true. The `select` function is its buddy which selects those positions from a sequence.